# Bluetooth printing issue with printer when already paired to device react-native-thermal-printer (android)

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth, thermal-printer, bluetooth-printing

I am using [react-native-thermal-printer](https://github.com/AllInOneYT/react-native-thermal-printer) for printing via bluetooth. It's working properly when my device is not paired with printer. but it's giving not able to connect error when my device is already paired with printer.

Here is the method i'm using to print,

```
   await ThermalPrinterModule.printBluetooth({
          macAddress: macAddress,
          payload: `[L]<font size='small'>amount:</font>\n`,
          autoCut: true,
        });
```

This is the error message i'm getting while printing with already paired device.

[image]

Here is the version of react-native-thermal-printer i'm using

```
"react-native-thermal-printer": "^2.3.6",
```

I have checked with android 11 and 12 version. I am facing same issue in both versions.

Thanks for the help in advance.